# Failed to connect to Layer while using Ios Device

Tags: ios, layer

While running on Device(Ipad mini2), layer is not connected and shows the following error:

```
Failed to connect to Layer: 
Optional
(
  Error Domain=SPDYSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "No endpoints available, unable to connect socket" 
  UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No endpoints available, unable to connect socket}
)
```

I've also disabled ATS from the plist manually, but still getting the same error.

Kindly help me to solve this issues.

Comment: Same issue with me

Comment: @hiteshlandge just Reset the Network setting of your device.